# Git "write failed, file system is full fatal: unable to write new_index file"

Tags: filesystems, kernel, git, openbsd

I am running OpenBSD 5.7 and am modifying the kernel for a university assignment. It's running in a virtual machine.

I cloned the repository into '/usr/src' and started to modify 1 file. I went

```
$ cd /usr/src/sys/conf/files
$ nano files
$ git add files 
/usr/src: write failed, file system is full
error: unable to create temporary file: No space left on device
error: sys/conf/files: failed to insert into database
error: unable to index file sys/conf/files
fatal: updating files failed
$ df -ih
Filesystem     Size    Used   Avail Capacity iused   ifree  %iused  Mounted on
/dev/wd0a      731M   73.6M    620M    11%    1775  117263     1%   /
/dev/wd0k      7.0G    2.3M    6.6G     0%     284  935138     0%   /home
/dev/wd0d      1.1G   10.0K    1.1G     0%       6  155896     0%   /tmp
/dev/wd0f      1.5G    370M    1.1G    25%   11751  196119     6%   /usr
/dev/wd0g      895M    191M    660M    22%    9183  120735     7%   /usr/X11R6
/dev/wd0h      3.2G    169M    2.9G     5%    5041  436685     1%   /usr/local
/dev/wd0j      1.8G   1000M    710M    58%   26924  232914    10%   /usr/obj
/dev/wd0i      1.2G    1.2G   -8.0K   100%   70321  111565    39%   /usr/src
/dev/wd0e      1.7G    8.1M    1.6G     0%     582  233272     0%   /var
```

Not sure why this is happening. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
Filesystem     Size    Used   Avail Capacity iused   ifree  %iused  Mounted on
/dev/wd0i      1.2G    1.2G   -8.0K   100%   70321  111565    39%   /usr/src
```

/usr/src is full.  Probably because you git cloned the kernel source onto it.

There seems to be 6.6GB free on /home, maybe you could do your work in `~/src`.  Clean up the mess in /usr/src first.

Comment: Is there a way to expand /usr/src?

Comment: not without a lot of file and partition shuffling.  i know how to do that on linux but you'd have to ask a freebsd expert for details on how to do it on freebsd.  BTW, this shows why having separate partitions for /usr, /var, /usr/src, /home etc isn't as good an idea as it once was (back in the '80s when disks were tiny and expensive).  if this was just one big / partition, you'd have about 14.6G to work with.  instead, you've got a lot of wasted space on parititions that will probably never be filled (e.g. /var using 8.1M out of 1.6G, and /usr/local with 169M used out of 2.9G).